# Getting an error when checking the length of a variable that might be null

Tags: c#

I am using the following:

```
if (Model.Notes.Length == null || Model.Notes.Length < 170) {
```

But there is an error when the Notes value is null. I thought this would allow it to work but I still get the error. Can someone tell me how I can make this work even if Model.Notes is null?

Comment: With regards to the below answers, unless `Length` is a nullable type (which I doubt) you won't be able to compile `Model.Notes.Length == null`. But otherwise they're correct. I'm sure your intent, Gemma, is `if(Model.Notes == null || Model.Notes.Length < 170)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a null check before accessing any properties.

```
if (Model.Notes!=null)
{

  if(Model.Notes.Length == null || Model.Notes.Length < 170)
  {
      //do the same awesome thing..
  }

}
```

Comment: damn. I think you might have the edge here with the //do awesome

Answer (score 1):

You gotta do:

```
if ((Model.Notes != null && (Model.Notes.Length == null || Model.Notes.Length < 170))
```

So it'll check for notes being null first.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if (Model.Notes != null && (Model.Notes.Length == null || Model.Notes.Length < 170)) {
```